# Different key in model than in database?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a database with a table that has a numeric field as the primary key.  I would like to however use a field that is in the table (that is a string) as the primary key.  Is this possible?

here is the database Table (I want to use the user_nme as the key in the model):

[image]

and here is the class:

namespace PTEManager.Domain
{
    public partial class OpsUser
    {
        public int u_user_id { get; set; }

```
    public Guid DepartmentID { get; set; }

    public string email_addr { get; set; }

    public string first_nme { get; set; }

    public string last_nme { get; set; }

    public Guid msrepl_tran_version { get; set; }

    public string status { get; set; }

    public string user_nme { get; set; }

    public int u_branch_id { get; set; }

}
```

}

and the mapping:

```
namespace PTEManager.Domain.Mapping
{
    class UserMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<OpsUser>
    {
        public UserMap()
        {
            // Primary Key
            this.HasKey(t => t.u_user_id);

            // Properties
            this.Property(t => t.DepartmentID);

            this.Property(t => t.email_addr)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(50);

            this.Property(t => t.first_nme)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(30);

            this.Property(t => t.last_nme)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(30);

            this.Property(t => t.msrepl_tran_version)
                .IsRequired();

            this.Property(t => t.status)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(1);

            this.Property(t => t.user_nme)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(15);

            this.Property(t => t.u_branch_id)
                .IsRequired();

            // Table & Column Mappings
            this.ToTable("users");
            this.Property(t => t.u_user_id).HasColumnName("u_user_id");
            this.Property(t => t.DepartmentID).HasColumnName("DepartmentID");
            this.Property(t => t.email_addr).HasColumnName("email_addr");
            this.Property(t => t.first_nme).HasColumnName("first_nme");
            this.Property(t => t.last_nme).HasColumnName("last_nme");
            this.Property(t => t.msrepl_tran_version).HasColumnName("msrepl_tran_version");
            this.Property(t => t.status).HasColumnName("status");
            this.Property(t => t.user_nme).HasColumnName("user_nme");
            this.Property(t => t.u_branch_id).HasColumnName("u_branch_id");
        }
    }
}
```

Is this feasible? and if so how? do I just mark it as the key in the mapping?

Comment: Just change this to use the new key: `this.HasKey(t => t.u_user_id);`  If you're using code first migrations then the database schema should be updated automatically.  Otherwise you'll also need to update your database schema to reflect the new key.  (And I suspect you may be able to deprecate the old one entirely if nothing else is using it.)

Comment: Do not use it as the key. Use the id as the key but generate a unique index for the user-Name.